# Multiple table relationship for country, state, area to design a parcel delivery management in Spring boot

Tags: sql, table-relationships

I want to build a software for parcel delivery system and need advice about how to build multiple table relationship.

Here, I am thinking about some dependent dropdown options. First of all, the receptionsit will select the name of the destined country, for example, USA. After that, in another dropdown all the states will appear. Let's say we select NY, then in another dropdown all the areas of NY will appear (Bronx, Manhattan, Queens, Brooklyn etc.).

There will be three tables

1. Country
2. State
3. Area

I designed the database and maintained **one to many** and **many to one bi-directional relationship**. For example,
(The USA has multiple states ----> Every state has multiple areas) (Multiple areas reside under one state ---> Multiple states reside under the USA)

This is bi-directional. I know that the best practice is to make uni-directional relationship. Do you think that this table relationship is okay or should I use uni-directional relationship?

Comment: Uni and bidirectional relationships are ORM concepts, not mysql ones.